# Elasticsearch query multi_match

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to create an elasticsearch query that looks for multiple fields. This works fine so far. However, I would like to refine this.
Let's say the word was indexed: "test". However, when I search for "tes" he does not find that word for me, but I would like to show it already - but the combination with my query brings me to a challenge.

```
             {
             "multi_match" : {
               "query":      "*" + query + "*",
               "type":       "cross_fields",
               "operator":   "and",
               "fields":     ["article.number^1","article.name_de^1", "article.name_en^5", "article.name_fr^5", "article.description^1"],
               "tie_breaker": 0,
             }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your constraints, here are your options.

If you wish to use wildcard before/after your search term, you can use [wildcard query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html). This has high processing cost at query time.

If you are fine with additional storage cost, you can opt to tokenize your input during analysis process. See [ngram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html). Beware that if you have long strings, it can quickly explode the storage requirement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But can not I use wildcard to search for the words in different fields? (Cross_fields). I looked at Ngram. If I look on the basis of my example I get in the search "test", also "tes" if min_ngram is set to 3.

The search is already good, but I have the problem when I search for "tes" I get no results but in "test" already - because he is looking for the whole term. Wildcard works great, but if I search for the following: "Test1 Test2", Test1 is in Field A and Test2 is in Field B - I will not get results anymore.

Comment: "wildcard" for multiple fields - you need to use compound queries like "bool" query and add multiple wildcard queries in should clause.

Comment: "ngram" - If you set min_ngram to 2 and max_ngram to 5 for example, it will create multiple terms in index like ["te", "tes", "test", "test1", "test2"]. You can then use "term" query to exactly match the term, which is optimized for query time.

Comment: perfect answer - Vishal Shukla, thank you very much!