# ElasticSearch: How can matches be sorted by where they are found in the field

Tags: elasticsearch

Example:
We have three documents:

```
doc1 {
 "field1": "xxxyyyzzz"
}

doc2 {
   "field1": "yyyxxxzzz" 
}

doc3 {
   "field1": "yyyzzzxxx"
}
```

When searching for "xxx", the search result should be:
doc1, doc2, doc3 in this order.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54863990/elasticsearch-query-multi-match/54864420#54864420 solve your problem?

Comment: @Vishal Shukla: We already use ngram tokenizer, all three documents are found but the order is wrong.

Comment: @VishalShukla: No, stackoverflow.com/questions/54863990/… doesn't solve my problem. The problem is the order of the documents that are found.

Comment: Added solution. Kindly acknowledge if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use prefix query and wildcard query combined with negative score if that match term is found in the end. This uses the default analyser. Note that this is a performance killer.

```
POST /test_index/test/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
               {
                "prefix": {
                  "field1": {
                     "value": "xxx",
                     "boost": 15
                  }
                }
               },
               {
               "wildcard": {
                   "field1": {
                      "value": "*xxx*", 
                      "boost": 10
                   }
                }
               },
               {
                   "wildcard": {
                   "field1": {
                      "value": "*xxx", 
                      "boost": -5
                   }
                }
               }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This will fulfil the requirement but using wildcard will have a performance hit. Specially the wildcard on both sides : `*xxx*`

Comment: I fully agree, it is a performance killer as mentioned. For this requirement, I don't see better solution either.